# Файл конфигурации .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Всем привет! Есть небольшая проблема, подскажите пожалуйста!
Есть сайт объявлений, в нем есть категории по товарам. к примеру, я нахожусь в категории "Мебель" ("http://www.abaza.miltor.ru/mebel/"), и на странице с категориями есть кнопка(ссылочная) при нажатии на которую, мне нужно оставаться на той же странице, но теперь передать параметр как здесь - "http://www.abaza.miltor.ru/mebel/user_site=123.ru"
Что нужно прописать в файле .htaccess, чтобы это заработало?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: К файлу .htaccess этот вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения. Чтобы "передать параметр в ссылочной кнопке" надо просто этот параметр к ней дописать.

Comment: Хорошо, я сделал так. Но не работает. Ссылка `<a style="text-decoration: none" href="http://www.samara.'.$global_domen_name.$mas_category['category_path'].'
                          user_site='.$site_name.'">` При переходе пишет, что страница не найдена и получается такой адрес в адресной строке: `http://www.samara.miltor/strojmaterialy/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20user_site=123.ru`

Comment: Откуда появляются эти "%20"?

Comment: %20 - это пробел. Берется он из переменной, которую ты выводишь